# Reduce distance computation overhead between a point and several rectangles

Tags: geometry

We are given several rectangles in the plane, without loss of generality, assume there are three of them, namely $R_1$, $R_2$ and $R_3$.

For a point $P$, we can compute three distances $d_1$, $d_2$ and $d_3$ between $P$ and each rectangle respectively, and a final distance $d_{min}$ is defined as $d_{min}=\min (d_1,d_2,d_3)$.

There are $n$ such points randomly scattered in the plane, and we want to know $d_{min}$ for every point. The naive solution would require $3n$ distance computations.

I'm wondering whether we can do some preprocess to $R_1$, $R_2$ and $R_3$ to reduce the number of distance computation. Or, put it another way, can we compute $d_{min}$ directly according to some aggregated information of $R_1$, $R_2$ and $R_3$, instead of computing $d_1$, $d_2$ and $d_3$ at first?

[image: depiction]

Comment: i think you will have to define the point of the rectangles (center, vertex) from where you want to compute the distance

Answer (score 0):

If the rectangles are not too many, you can store the [Voronoi diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) of your configuration in a convenient way (as a set of linear and quadratic inequalities, for instance), then find, for each point $P$, the index $i$ of the region where it belongs, in order to compute only $d(P,R_i)$.